# CSS - Change DIV's width depending on contained text's width

Tags: jquery, html, css, text, width

Recently I found [this good-looking example](http://codepen.io/iraycd/pen/dHrxv) for implementing some kind of material design for buttons.

Each button is composed of several classes so it can be customized just by modifying one of them. My problem is, I want the buttons to change their width along with the text they contain.

In short, a "button" is created this way:

```
<div class="button flat">
    <div class="center" fit><b>NOT NOW</b></div>
    <!--A custom tag, it came with the [original example][2]-->
    <paper-ripple fit></paper-ripple>
</div>
```

I need the parent div width (the one with classes "button" and "flat") to change depending on the inner div's (with class "center") contained text. I tried several ways using only CSS, but being new to it, I didn't find the way to get the "real width" of the inner div's text, or to "wrap it". So then I found a solution using jQuery/Javascript. [Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Olmectron/m0jfaLzr/6/) using that solution.

However, **my question is if there's a way for doing something like [this in the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Olmectron/m0jfaLzr/6/), but using only HTML and CSS.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need div exactly? Why you can't just use button or styled anchor. With button element you can use padding, and there will always be some fixed space between letters and edges. Check this for example http://codepen.io/suez/pen/4f1faf8d2ba4b689a0441ee5ea44e8b1

Comment: I thing I'll try something like that. After hours and hours of searching for CSS complex coding or anything like that, I was not able to do what I wanted with the divs. Thank you Nikolay.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using CSS min-width rule on width property in .button class

```
.button {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      min-width:60px;
      width:auto;
      height: 32px;
      line-height: 32px;
      border-radius: 2px;
      font-size: 0.9em;
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #646464;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, it didin't work. I tried it before, but without the "width: auto;". Still the same result, it gets zero width doing this, no matter the contained text length.